# Lightning datatable default padding for some columns is 0

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I am using simple wrapper for lightning datatable. I have removed all custom style from all related files, removed all params passed to columns, but i have padding: 0 for my currency. Here is code from inspector. Any ides what to do with padding or why is it here?

```
<td lightning-datatable_table="" style="padding: 0;" role="gridcell" aria-readonly="true" tabindex="0" data-label="Price" data-col-key-value="Price__c-currencyFormatted-4" class="">
```

Here is my code

```
      getColumns() {
            let columns = [];
            this.columns.forEach(column => {
                if(column.type === 'date') {
                    columns.push({
                        fieldName: column.fieldName,
                        label: column.label,
                        type: 'CustomDate',
                    });
                }
                else if(column.type === 'currency') {
                    columns.push({
                        fieldName: column.fieldName,
                        label: column.label,
                        type: 'CustomCurrency',
                    });
                }
                else {
                    columns.push(column);
                }
            });
            return columns;
```

Update: Other columns don't have that style. It seems that problem exist only for data from sObject, because there are no padding for such code.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example